# Can't get USB/IP to work

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, usb

I have Ubuntu 16.04,  and USB cash device plugged on it. 
I want to share this cash device through USBIP. So I plugged this device and

```
usbip list --local
```

Then I see my device (emphasized with bold)

- busid 3-1 (09da:f613)
  unknown vendor : unknown product (09da:f613)
- busid 3-2 (1532:0216)
  unknown vendor : unknown product (1532:0216)

  **- busid 1-1.3.1 (2912:0005)**
  **unknown vendor : unknown product (2912:0005)**
- busid 1-1.3.2 (13fe:4200)
  unknown vendor : unknown product (13fe:4200)
- busid 1-1.3.4 (0cf3:9271)
  unknown vendor : unknown product (0cf3:9271)
  So I want to bind it and getting an error:

  root@xxxxx:~# usbip -d bind -b 1-1.3.1

And output is

```
 usbip: debug: usbip.c:141:[run_command] running command: `bind'
 usbip: debug: sysfs_utils.c:18:[write_sysfs_attribute] error opening 
 attribute /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbip-host/match_busid
 usbip: debug: utils.c:50:[modify_match_busid] failed to write match_busid: No such file or directory
 usbip: error: unable to bind device on 1-1.3.1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Solution found:

```
modprobe usbip_core
modprobe usbip_host
```

Comment: To avoid problems "
     libusbip: error: udev_device_new_from_subsystem_sysname failed
"
don't forget to run

    modprobe vhci-hcd